# Is it possible to create a new graph in Galaxybase via JavaAPI?

Tags: graph-databases

I'm new to Galaxybase and I always build graphs directly in the visualization platform. Is it possible to create a new graph in Galaxybase via JavaAPI?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create a new graph by `Galaxybase.newGraph()`